# SQL frequency counting in a dataset

Tags: java, sql, dataset, frequency

I have a dataset with an ID and value. For each value I want to get its corresponding frequency in the dataset. **What is the most efficient pure SQL query-based solution?** (that is not using java etc...) Or would it be more efficient to use Java with SQL?

1. I am using Derby SQL

This is my previous solution for this problem

1. Get all distinct values in a new table and add a frequency column
2. Write Java code to iterate through all distinct values in this new table and run a counting query against the original dataset

I would really like to avoid the extra Java code...

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value)
  FROM dataset
```

Comment: This isn't what I'd call "frequency"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Value, COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset) AS Frequency
FROM dataset
GROUP BY Value
```

Comment: I believe this is relative frequency/proportion? Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes - and thats how I understood your question